# MS Graph Search Custom Connector is not synchronized

Tags: search, graph, synchronization, microsoft-graph-api

Recently Microsoft published the **Microsoft Search API (beta)** which provides the possibility to index external systems by creating a  **MS Graph search custom connector**.

To achieve this I created 2 Search Custom Connectors:

- one according to [Microsoft Graph Search Connector Sample from GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-search-connector-sample)
- and one on my own, step by step according to the [official MS instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/indexing-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

  1. Create the Connector app in Azure

     - Add app registration (Single tenant)
     - Add required API permissions and give admin consent
     - Add a  client secret
  2. Get access token (via Postman)

     - Get the required parameters from app registration
     - Submit a login request to get the (bearer) token
  3. Create a new connection (via Postman)
  4. Registering a schema (via Postman)
  5. Add items to the search index (via Postman)

Both variants worked well so far but if I now try a search (for example via Bing (activated for our O365 tenant, or in the *Microsoft Search Center*, logged in as the appropriate account) no results from the custom connectors are shown.

Via *Graph Explorer*, logged in as the appropriate account and using the query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query, I get an http status 500 ("InternalServerError", "The call failed, please try again."): [Screenshot from Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqU0V.png)

Under *> Microsoft 365 admin center > Microsoft Search > Connectors* both connectors are displayed but there is displayed neither any status nor any successful synchronisation: [screenshot from MS 365 Search admin center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSF5X.png)

I know the Microsoft Search API in still in preview but I wonder if it works at all?

- **Is there any possibility to trigger the synchronisation manually?**
- **Or at least find out what's going wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a new Result Type and Vertical as well in the Search center?

I followed the steps mentioned in the [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-search-connector-sample) and the search works for me in Office 365.

Regarding the synchronization, I don't think that is available in the Search center as of now because there is no option to edit the connection or set any synchronization schedule. However, I'm still exploring other options to synchronize as its quite new to me.

Comment: I already had created a vertical but not yet a result type (since I thought I'd see the results from the connector in the "All" tab and therefore vertical and result type were not really necessary).
But after creating the result type I can now see the results at least in the dedicated connectors tab ("vertical"). That's much better than before!
But what I really need to achieve: displaying the results within the "global" Microsoft search, at least in the Modern SharePoint Search Center (best within Bing and Office, too). Do you have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Nope...the connector results do not appear in the All vertical or bing search even for the Microsoft provided Service Now connector or other custom connectors...I hope this limitation would be addressed when connectors go into General Availability